Weblogic Server wldf configuration
wldf configuration when jvm utilization is greater than 85 percent in weblogic 12.2.1.4.0
What will be the policy expression
Rule Expression: Click on Add Expressions.
Severity: Warning (or as per your preference)
Type: Metric Attribute
MBean Type: weblogic.management.runtime.JVMRuntimeMBean
Attribute: HeapFreePercent
Operator: <
Threshold: 15 (because if HeapFreePercent < 15%, it means utilization is > 85%)
I did this but getting invalid
